# where uboot decompress- UImage

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

Uboot use to decompress the UImage lying in the NAND & then load it to the LOADADDR.

http://blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=bootloaders:u-boot:uimage

> decompresses the image at the specified address (in this case
>   “0x1000000”) to its load address “0x1000”.  Care must be taken that
>   the decompressed image does not over-write the compressed image.  To
>   determine if this will be a problem - the size of the decompressed
>   image (which is only known at compression time) should be added to the
>   load address.  If the compressed image is located anywhere overlapping
>   the destination of the decompressed image, you will have problems.

Here in this link `bootm 0x1000000` is loading the image at address 0x1000000 to its load address “0x1000”.

My question is where the UImage is getting decompressed ? Is it decompress in RAM or NAND ?

http://blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=bootloaders:u-boot:tftp_loading_files

> Here we loaded the uImage file into external memory at address
>   0x1000000.  Then we proceeded to boot it. Keep in mind that compressed
>   images (like uImages),  the address of the uImage needs to be
>   different from that of the load address of the executable  and that it
>   needs to be loaded outside of the decompressed file. Our kernel here
>   loads at 0x1000 and is only 3.8 megs,  so the load address of the
>   uImage at 16 meg (0x1000000) is clearly outside of the decompression
>   range.

Here in above link author is saying "so the load address of the uImage at 16 meg (0x1000000) is clearly outside of the decompression range" What exactly it mean ?

And how to take care that decompresssed image not overwrite the Compressed image ?

Comment: Please anyone who can answer this question ??

Comment: U-Boot (for ARM anyway) must load the uImage file into RAM before it can decompress it.  (Note the spelling & capitalization.)  BTW: Avoid using Blackfin documentation when you are using an ARM SoC.  The different architectures may do things differently.

Comment: In case of 32 bit ARM MCU, first Uboot will get inside RAM then it will load the compressed uimage in RAM then uboot will decompress the uIMage to LOADADDR.
   So to defining LOADADDR (uncompressed image addre